# Insert PostgreSQL psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Спарсил некоторые данные, сейчас хочу вставить их в таблицу

```
def add_to_database(product):
    sql = "INSERT INTO parser_out(product_id, serial, code, name, article, label, release, format, package, count_disks," \
          " sounding, genres, weight, status, playlist, description, count_images, images, count_videos, videos) " \
          "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    for test in product:
        print(type(test), test)


    data = (product["product_id"],
            product["serial"],
            product["code"],
            product["name"],
            product["article"],
            product["label"],
            product["release"],
            product["format"],
            product["package"],
            product["count_disks"],
            product["sounding"],
            product["genres"],
            product["weight"],
            product["status"],
            product["playlist"],
            product["description"],
            product["count_images"],
            product["images"],
            product["count_videos"],
            product["videos"])
    print("Добавление записи", data)
    database_resuest(sql, data)

def database_resuest(sql_request, data):
    with closing(ps.connect(dbname=config["db_name"], user=config["db_user"], password=config["db_password"],
                            host=config["db_host"])) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            if data is None:
                cursor.execute(sql_request)
            else:
                cursor.execute(sql_request, data)
                conn.commit()
            return cursor.fetchall()
```

Но у меня выкидывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danil/PycharmProjects/untitled/parser.py", line 268, in <module>
    main_parse()
  File "C:/Users/danil/PycharmProjects/untitled/parser.py", line 237, in main_parse
    parse("https://collectomania.ru/product/samson-francois-debussy-childrens-corner-estampes-suite-bergamasque-pour-le-piano-lp", "test", "test", 12)
  File "C:/Users/danil/PycharmProjects/untitled/parser.py", line 186, in parse
    add_to_database(product)
  File "C:/Users/danil/PycharmProjects/untitled/parser.py", line 222, in add_to_database
    database_resuest(sql, data)
  File "C:/Users/danil/PycharmProjects/untitled/parser.py", line 44, in database_resuest
    cursor.execute(sql_request, data)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Tag'
```

Я проверил типы, но они все str

```
<class 'str'> name
<class 'str'> product_id
<class 'str'> serial
<class 'str'> code
<class 'str'> article
<class 'str'> label
<class 'str'> release
<class 'str'> format
<class 'str'> package
<class 'str'> count_disks
<class 'str'> sounding
<class 'str'> genres
<class 'str'> status
<class 'str'> weight
<class 'str'> playlist
<class 'str'> description
<class 'str'> count_images
<class 'str'> images
<class 'str'> count_videos
<class 'str'> videos
```

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, почему так происходит, но помогло принудительное конвертирование для всех полей в

```
data = (
        str(product["product_id"]),
        str(product["serial"]),
        str(product["code"]),
        str(product["name"]),
        str(product["article"]),
        str(product["label"]),
        str(product["release"]),
        str(product["format"]),
        str(product["package"]),
        str(product["count_disks"]),
        str(product["sounding"]),
        str(product["genres"]),
        str(product["weight"]),
        str(product["status"]),
        str(product["playlist"]),
        str(product["description"]),
        str(product["count_images"]),
        str(product["images"]),
        str(product["count_videos"]),
        str(product["videos"])
    )
    print("Добавление записи", data)
    database_resuest(sql, data)
```

Происходит потому что `psycopg2` конвертирует данные из типов питона в типы постгреса. Поддержиывает строки, числа, айпиадреса, ууиды. Но ваш парсер собирает данные из html и держит их в типе `Tag` о котором `psycopg2` ничего не знает.

В вопросе возможно неправильно проверили типы.

Метод `.get_text()` или `text` в парсере должен извлекать текст из html. Возможно гдето `contents` вместо text, в который на каком-то из элементов попался вложенный tag.

Comment: @eri Единственный блок, который содержал html код я принудительно перевел в string.
Поэтому я думал, как я могу получать эту ошибку, если я и так конвертировал. Возможно я где-то проморгал, поэтому я решил все поля конвертировать